# Raipidfire Survey Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rapidfire-gem

I'm trying to build a survey application with the rapidfire gem. I can create a question group but when I try to answer a question i get the error `undefined method primary_key`?

Does anyone know why I'm getting this? I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby on rails 3.2.16

Comment: Need more information, did you follow the install steps: 

    $ bundle install
    $ bundle exec rake rapidfire:install:migrations
    $ bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: i used rails 4 and the problem went away

Comment: I would love it if you could show your code so I can help debug it